# flag rows in a dataframe conditionally on values of other rows

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe `df_in = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0,1,2,2,3,4,4,4], 'channel': [0,1,0,1,3,2,3,1]})`

```
> df_in

   id  channel
0   0        0
1   1        1
2   2        0
3   2        1
4   3        3
5   4        2
6   4        3
7   4        1
```

And a list of 2-tuples `allowed_channel_couples = ((0,1),(2,3))`.

I'd like to obtain a new dataframe `df_out` as:

```
   id  channel  flag
0   0        0     0
1   1        1     0
2   2        0     1
3   2        1     1
4   3        3     0
5   4        2     1
6   4        3     1
7   4        1     0
```

Each rows in `df_out` equals the rows in `df_in`. However, `df_out` contains a new column, named `flag`. The `flag` value of a row in `df_out` is equal 1 only if another row with same `id` exists whose channel value 'matches' the channel value of the first row, according to `allowed_channel_couples`.

Hence consider the row with index 5 of `df_in`. This row has `id` equal 4 and `channel` equal 2. Since the row at index 6 has `id` equal 4 and `channel` value equal 3, and `(2,3)` is in `allowed_channel`, both the row with index 5 and the row with index 6 are marked with the flag `1`.
On the other hand, the row with index 7 of `df_in` has `id` equal 4 and `channel` equal 1. The allowed couple for flagging in this case is `(0,1)`. No other rows with `id` equal 4 and channel equal 0 exists, hence the row with index 7 is marked with a 0.

I'm having troubles in solving this problem avoiding python's slow loops. Any idea on how I can obtain the flags column efficiently?

### Ideas:

- I've tried working with the `agg` method. Hence I'm able to obtain a table like:

```
   id    channel
0   0        [0]
1   1        [1]
2   2     [0, 1]
3   3        [3]
4   4  [2, 3, 1]
```

through `df_in.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'channel': lambda x: tuple(x)})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the values from one of the tuple values to the other, then identify the duplicates:

```
d = dict(allowed_channel_couples)
# {0: 1, 2: 3}

df_in['flag'] = (df_in
 .assign(channel=df_in['channel'].map(d).fillna(df_in['channel']))
 .duplicated(['id', 'channel'], keep=False)
 .astype(int)
)
```

output:

```
   id  channel  flag
0   0        0     0
1   1        1     0
2   2        0     1
3   2        1     1
4   3        3     0
5   4        2     1
6   4        3     1
7   4        1     0
```

Comment: absolutely sick. thank you truly. i would have never guessed that. can I ask you where you learned to do this? i'd like to learn too.

Comment: I learned by reading the documentation and coding ;)